# How to get address of cell which calls a VBA Functions in a Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a function to get the address of a cell which call a VBA function ?

I used "Application.ActiveCell.Address" , but found that this method is not a correct way to get the address of calling cell.

e.g: If we have excel sheet with saved VBA functions, Once you reopen the sheet, the above method will not work.

please help

nimo

Comment: @nimo, is the function a UDF? Can you maybe give some code as an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: `ThisCell` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834969.aspx

Answer (score 28):

You can use Application.Caller, but you would probably be best to pass the cell to the function.

```
   With Application.Caller
        CallerRows = .Rows.Count
        CallerCols = .Columns.Count
        CallerAddr = .Address
   End With
```

See: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

To pass the cell:

```
 =SomeFunction(A1)
```

Where the code has:

```
SomeFunction(r)
```

Comment: Just found out that I asked the same question: [How do I find out which cell a VBA Function was called from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559279/excel-cell-from-which-a-function-is-called)