# VBA: How to display an error message just like the standard error message which has a "Debug" button?

Tags: vba, scripting, excel, ms-office

I created an error-handler using `On Error Goto` statement, and I put a few lines of cleaning code and display the error message, but now I don't want to lose the comfortableness of the default handler which also points me to the exact line where the error has occured. How can I do that?

Comment: Just to keep the proper links ... this question continues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929997/vba-how-to-make-the-current-cursor-in-vbe-jump-to-the-line-where-the-last-error/3930626#3930626

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**First the good news.** This code does what you want (please note the "line numbers")

```
Sub a()
 10:    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
 20:    DivisionByZero = 1 / 0
 30:    Exit Sub
 ErrorHandler:
 41: If Err.Number <> 0 Then
 42:    Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
 43:    MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
 44:    End If
 50:    Resume Next
 60: End Sub
```

When it runs, the expected MsgBox is shown:

[image]

**And now the bad news:** 
Line numbers are a residue of old versions of Basic. The programming environment usually took charge of inserting and updating them. In VBA and other "modern" versions, this functionality is lost.

However, [Here](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=120898&page=1) there are several alternatives for "automatically" add line numbers, saving you the tedious task of typing them ... but all of them seem more or less cumbersome ... or commercial.

HTH!

Comment: MZTools can add/remove line numbers & its free

Comment: @Charles yep. That is one of the references in the page I cited. Tnx!

Comment: @belisarius, thanks so much for the code, precious info, and useful external references. Just curious, is there a way to bring the line to reader's focus, even highlight them and enter debugging mode? Is that really internal functionality?

Comment: @Vantomex Glad to help. I don't know if there is a way to do that. Perhaps you may look at VBIDE.dll ... but I'm NOT sure. Good luck!

Comment: @Vantomex, you could also look at the help for 'Application.Goto', which you can use to at least jump to the right procedure in the IDE.

Comment: Actually, 'Application.Goto' could also be used with 'Application.Caller' to better answer your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861431/vba-how-to-get-the-last-used-cell-by-vba-code-when-the-last-error-occured-in-a-w

Comment: @jtolle, I successfully made the cursor jump to a procedure name using `Application.Goto`, however what actually I want is to make the cursor goto the line (in VBE) where the error last occured. I think I will ask a new question about this one.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way simply disable the error handler in your error handler if it does not match the error types you are doing and resume.

The handler below checks agains each error type and if none are a match it returns error resume to normal VBA ie GoTo 0 and resumes the code which then tries to rerun the code and the normal error block pops up.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

x = 1/0

ErrorHandler:
if Err.Number = 13 then ' 13 is Type mismatch (only used as an example)

'error handling code for this

end if

If err.Number = 1004 then ' 1004 is Too Large (only used as an example)

'error handling code for this

end if

On Error GoTo 0
Resume
```

Comment: When I try:  'On Error GoTo 0 ; Resume' in Excel VBA in Office 365, I see failure message: "Run-time error '20':  Resume without error"

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not address the Debug button (you'd have to design a form and use the buttons on that to do something like the method in your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3929997/2712565)). But it does address this part:

> now I don't want to lose the comfortableness of the default handler which also point me to the exact line where the error has occured.

First, I'll assume you don't want this in production code - you want it either for debugging or for code you personally will be using. I use a compiler flag to indicate debugging; then if I'm troubleshooting a program, I can easily find the line that's causing the problem.

```
# Const IsDebug = True

Sub ProcA()
On Error Goto ErrorHandler
' Main code of proc

ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Close objects and stuff here
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, , ThisWorkbook.Name & ": ProcA"
    #If IsDebug Then
        Stop            ' Used for troubleshooting - Then press F8 to step thru code 
        Resume          ' Resume will take you to the line that errored out
    #Else
        Resume ExitHere ' Exit procedure during normal running
    #End If
End Sub
```

Note: the exception to `Resume` is if the error occurs in a sub-procedure without an error handling routine, then `Resume` will take you to the line in this proc that called the sub-procedure with the error. But you can still step into and through the sub-procedure, using <kbd>F8</kbd> until it errors out again. If the sub-procedure's too long to make even that tedious, then your sub-procedure should probably have its own error handling routine.

There are multiple ways to do this. Sometimes for smaller programs where I know I'm gonna be stepping through it anyway when troubleshooting, I just put these lines right after the MsgBox statement:

```
    Resume ExitHere         ' Normally exits during production
    Resume                  ' Never will get here
Exit Sub
```

It will never get to the Resume statement, unless you're stepping through and set it as the next line to be executed, either by dragging the next statement pointer to that line, or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> with the cursor on that line.

Here's an article that expands on these concepts: [Five tips for handling errors in VBA](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/).  Finally, if you're using VBA and haven't discovered Chip Pearson's awesome site yet, he has a page explaining [Error Handling In VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ErrorHandling.htm).

Answer (score 0):

For Me I just wanted to see the error in my VBA application so in the function I created the below code..

```vb
Function Database_FileRpt
'-------------------------
On Error GoTo CleanFail
'-------------------------
'
' Create_DailyReport_Action and code


CleanFail:

'*************************************

MsgBox "********************" _

& vbCrLf & "Err.Number: " & Err.Number _

& vbCrLf & "Err.Description: " & Err.Description _

& vbCrLf & "Err.Source: " & Err.Source _

& vbCrLf & "********************" _

& vbCrLf & "...Exiting VBA Function: Database_FileRpt" _

& vbCrLf & "...Excel VBA Program Reset." _

, , "VBA Error Exception Raised!"

*************************************

 ' Note that the next line will reset the error object to 0, the variables 
above are used to remember the values
' so that the same error can be re-raised

Err.Clear

' *************************************

Resume CleanExit

CleanExit:

'cleanup code , if any, goes here. runs regardless of error state.

Exit Function  ' SUB  or Function    

End Function  ' end of Database_FileRpt

' ------------------
```