# VBA: How to make the current cursor in VBE jump to the line where the last error occured?

Tags: vba, scripting, excel, ms-office

This is still related with my previous questions, [VBA: How to display an error message just like the standard error message which has a “Debug” button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911973/vba-how-to-display-an-error-message-just-like-the-standard-error-message-which-h)

Now, I successfully make the current cursor in VBE jump to a particular procedure in VBE. I used `Application.Goto` to achieve this. However, what actually I want is to make the current cursor in VBE jump to the line where the last error occured. I suspected there should be something useful for this purpose in `Application.VBE` object but didn't know which?

Solving this also means satisfying my previous question entirely. Any hints or even dirty tricks?

Comment: Do you mind to post your code using Application.Goto?

Comment: `Application.Goto ("MyProcedureName")`

Comment: I just found `Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection` can be used to get the current line of the last executed code, but not the last line where the error occured.

Comment: @belisarius, well, it seems I start to think that you're one of the VBA superheroes. Thank you very much. It works perfect as expected. BTW, I'm OK for even a thousand line of codes (hopefully people too), sorry for wasting your time. :-)

Comment: While I've been interested to follow (and contribute to) the process of solving your puzzle, I'm wondering if you would mind explaining *why* you're interested in doing this? What is the problem you're solving? If this is just for helping with debugging, couldn't you just tell the VBE to "break on all errors" (under Tools...Options...General...Error Trapping)?

Comment: Oh, I'm not aware of that. I must confess that I'm a newcomer in VBA programming (IIRC, three weeks ago). I just think at a glance, VBA custom error handling make me loose the comfortableness of the standard error handling in debugging perspective, apparently not, as you pointed. However, for me, this topic still a precious knowledge to the less-known VBE internal functionality.

Comment: Hey, keep on asking. Like I said, I found this set of questions interesting regardless of the reason they were asked.

Comment: @Vantomex, Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.GetSelection gets the line(s) of the selected code in VBE, it doesn't get the current line of the last executed code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continued from your previous question :)

I suppose you are already using line numbering (as answered in the previous question).

So, modify your error handling routine to something like:

```
Sub aa()
Dim zz As Long

10:     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
20:     DivisionByZero = 1 / 0
30:     Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
41:  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
42:     Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
43:     MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        zz = CodeFind("", "", Str(Erl), 0)
44:     End If
50:     Resume Next
End Sub
```

Now for the CodeFind() thing. I found it [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS_Access/Q_21471211.html) (at the bottom, the last one), but had to modify it a bit, so I'm posting a lot of code ... sorry.

Insert this code in a new module and be sure you have the reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3" checked, and the project is not protected. In doubt see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

HTH!

Here is the code

```
 Option Explicit
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ' Procedure : CodeFind
 ' DateTime  : 7/5/2005 18:32
 ' Author    : Nelson Hochberg
 ' Purpose   : Find a module, a procedure and/or a string in code and highlight it
 ' Returns   : 0 if not found,  line number in module if found
 ' Syntax    : lngReturn = CodeFind ([FindMod],[FindProc],[FindStr],[TypeOfSearch])
 ' Arguments : Optional FindMod As String: Part of a name of a module
 '             Optional FindProc As String: Part of a name of a procedure
 '             Optional FindStr As String: Part of a string to search
 '             NOTE: One of the above three is required
 '             Optional TypeOfSearch As Long: -1 Find line number, 0 Find string,
 '                      >0 Continue search starting at line number: TypeOfSearch + 1
 ' Thanks    : To stevbe at Experts Exchange for the initial code.
 '---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '
 Public Function CodeFind( _
 Optional FindMod As String = "", _
 Optional FindProc As String = "", _
 Optional FindStr As String = "", _
 Optional TypeOfSearch As Long = 0 _
 ) As Long

 Dim vbc As VBIDE.VBComponent
 Dim cm As VBIDE.CodeModule
 Dim VBAEditor As VBIDE.VBE
 Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject


 Dim startline As Long, startcol As Long, endline As Long, endcol As Long

 If FindMod <> "" Then
     CodeFind = FindModule(FindMod, vbc, cm)
         If CodeFind = False Then Exit Function
     If FindProc <> "" Then
         CodeFind = FindProcedure(FindProc, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm)
             If CodeFind = False Then Exit Function
         If FindStr <> "" Then
             CodeFind = FindString(FindStr, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm, TypeOfSearch)
                 If CodeFind = False Then Exit Function
         Else
             GoTo CodeLineFound
         End If
     Else
         startline = 1
         If FindStr <> "" Then
             CodeFind = FindString(FindStr, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm, TypeOfSearch)
             If CodeFind = False Then Exit Function
         Else
             GoTo CodeLineFound
         End If
     End If
 Else
     Set VBAEditor = Application.VBE
 '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
     Set VBProj = VBAEditor.ActiveVBProject
     For Each vbc In VBProj.VBComponents


         Set cm = vbc.CodeModule
         If FindProc <> "" Then
             CodeFind = FindProcedure(FindProc, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm)
             If CodeFind = False Then GoTo Nextvbc2 Else Exit For
         Else
             startline = 1
             If FindStr <> "" Then
                 CodeFind = FindString(FindStr, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm, TypeOfSearch)
                     If CodeFind = False Then GoTo Nextvbc2 Else Exit For
             Else
                 MsgBox "CodeFind: At least one of the following is required:" & vbCrLf & _
                     "    Module" & vbCrLf & "    Procedure" & vbCrLf & "    String"
                 CodeFind = False
                 Exit Function
             End If
         End If
 Nextvbc2:
     Next vbc
     If CodeFind <> False Then
         If FindStr <> "" Then
             CodeFind = FindString(FindStr, startline, startcol, endline, endcol, cm, TypeOfSearch)
             If CodeFind = False Then Exit Function
         Else
             GoTo CodeLineFound
         End If
     End If
 End If

 CodeLineFound:
 If CodeFind <> False Then
     If endline = -1 Then endline = 1
     If endcol = -1 Then endcol = 1
     cm.CodePane.Show
     cm.CodePane.SetSelection startline, startcol, endline, endcol
 End If

 End Function
```

Comment: I vote up first, acceptance will follow after I make a test. :-)

Comment: well, it seems I start to think that you're one of the VBA superheroes. Thank you very much. It works perfect as expected. BTW, I'm OK for even a thousand line of codes (hopefully people too), sorry for wasting your time. :-)

Comment: @Vantomex Glad to know it worked for you. The real credit is for the original author,although he intended to use the code for other purposes. I just customized a few lines. Also note that answering this kind of questions is by no means a waste of time as I also learn a lot in the process!