# Create UDF that works when dragged down

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-udf, vba

I think I'm overlooking something simple...

My idea is to create a function in Excel that's easier to set up than the following:
`=INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$5)/($B$1:$B$5=1),ROW(1:1)))`
(see [ScottCraner's comment in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1169304/529100) for that function in practice)

I have created the following UDF:

```
Public Function findUnique(ByVal indexRange As Range, matchRange As Range, matchVal As Long)
' Trying to create a dynamic function of:
' =INDEX($A$1:$A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$B$5)/($B$1:$B$5=1),ROW(1:1)))

 findUnique = Evaluate("=Index(" & indexRange.Address & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,Row(" & matchRange.Address & _
    ")/(" & matchRange.Address & "=" & matchVal & "),Row(" & ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row & ")))")

End Function
```

And it *almost* works. Except, when I drag down from the first row, the data doesn't update. I have to click into the cell to "retrigger" the function to get the correct data to show:

[image]

(Column D is that formula, entered correctly).

But, how do I get the formula to update automatically, without re-entering the cell?

I've also tried adding a fourth Variable:

```
Public Function findUnique(ByVal indexRange As Range, matchRange As Range, matchVal As Long, curRow as Long)

findUnique = Evaluate("=Index(" & indexRange.address & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,Row(" & matchRange.address & _
    ")/(" & matchRange.address & "=" & matchVal & "),Row(" & curRow & ":" & curRow & ")))")

End Function
```

and enter like: `=findUnique($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,1,ROW())`
but it just returns a `#VALUE` error

(Also, how do I avoid `ActiveCell.Row`, as I have it drilled in to my head to avoid using `Active` anything...)

Thanks for any thoughts or advice!

Comment: If you `debug.print ActiveCell.Row` - you'll see it's the thing dinging you. Haven't found a soln yet however.

Comment: @OldUgly I knew it! Haha yeah I figured that was the reason but can't figure why using `Row()` results in an error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259035/how-to-get-address-of-cell-which-calls-a-vba-functions-in-a-excel-sheet), try the following ...

```
 With Application.Caller
    CallerRow = .Row
 End With
 findUnique = Evaluate("=Index(" & indexRange.Address & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,Row(" & matchRange.Address & _
    ")/(" & matchRange.Address & "=" & matchVal & "),Row(" & CallerRow & ":" & CallerRow & ")))")
```

Comment: Aha, yes! I'll read more [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx), but quickly, I assume `.Caller` is referring to the cell that "called" the formula? That's great and works!